# Text in CheckedTextView can't be centered

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/charge_industry_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/charge3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ChargeIndustry"
            android:background="@drawable/checkedtextview_checked"/>
```

[image]

The text in the `CheckedTextView` can't be centered, when I make  `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Now I have resolved this problem by adding `android:textAlignment="center" `

Answer (score 7):

try  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

or `android:textAlignment="center"`

Comment: Now I have resolved this problem by adding `android:textAlignment="center"`,Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try it replacing  with  android:gravity="center". I hope it will work.. It works for me...

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Comment: I had tried that but it doesn't work. 
Now I have resolved this problem by adding `android:textAlignment="center"`,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me :

For text in **center**

```
                android:textAlignment="center"
```

For text on **right side/ end**

```
                android:textAlignment="inherit"
```

***android:gravity*** Tag is useless in its case